# paypal mode of payment in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I had posted following data to my paypal function in codeigniter controller

```
**Array
(
    [firstname] => firstname
    [email_id] => root@abc.com
    [address] => abc phase
    [select_country] => 1
    [select_state] => 1
    [select_city] => 1
    [zipcode] => 233234
    [address_same] => 0
    [shipping_address] => 
    [select_country3] => Select
    [shipping_state] =>abc 
    [shipping_city] => abc
    [zipcode3] => 123456
    [user_id] => 41
    [shipping_charge] => 50
    [grand_total] => 13569
    [quantity] => 1
    [payment_mode] => 1
    [submit] => submit
)**
```

i need to redirect my grand total and required data to paypal official link

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

what all i need to post ..?

please guide for further procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to HTML form like this :

Example your array is `$myArray`

```
<?php
    $rand=rand();
?>
<form id="paypal_<?php echo $rand;?>" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $myArray['email_id']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="hat">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $myArray['firstname']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe">
  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="9 Elm Street">
  <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Apt 5">
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Berwyn">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="PA">
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="19312">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="jdoe@zyzzyu.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="your_notify_url" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type='hidden' name='return' value="your_return_url"/>
  <input type="image" name="submit"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

Script for auto submit

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#paypal_<?php echo $rand;?>").submit();
});
</script>
```

For details https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/

Comment: last email will be user's email id? and i validate to at sandbox environment

Comment: `name="business"` this is paypal email id and `name="email"` is customer email id

Comment: okz on return i need to save my product details and order details to database how i will come to know whether transaction is successful ???

Comment: in `name="notify_url"` notify url. You get some `post` data after success/fail from paypal. if payment status is success then you make some code for insert data in your database on notify url page.

Comment: you are logging into the account of the seller for this purchase. Please change your login information and try again.  Getting this error for my buyer account why so any idea?